# How do I redirect from one DotNetNuke module to another?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, module, dotnetnuke

I am new to dotnetnuke.

I developed three modules in desktopmodules folder. like

```
desktopmodules(folder)

     |
     --  EnterpriseSearch(folder)
           EnterpriseSearch.ascx

     |
     -- document search(folder)
           docsearch.ascx

     |
     --result(folder)
           result.ascx
```

result page is common to enterprice search and document search i want to redirect to result page from EnterpriseSearch and docsearch with parameter.

I tried with placing result module "type" as "view" and method of `DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL`

I tried with placing result module "type" as "edit"

```
editurl()
```

but i am not able to redirect it.

I dont want place theree pages in one folder (according to my requirements)

please give me the solutions to my question

Comment: Please don't repost a question with more information, use the edit link below the question to edit it instead.

Answer (score 3):

1. Drop the EnterpriseSearch module onto a Content Page named EnterpriseSearch in your root DNN installation. Users will see "domain/EnterpriseSearch.aspx" in their address bar when visiting this page.
2. Drop the DocumentSearch module onto a Content Page named DocSearch in your root DNN installation. Users will see "domain/DocSearch.aspx" in their address bar when visiting this page.
3. Drop the Results module onto a Content Page named SearchResults in your root DNN installation. Users will see "domain/SearchResults.aspx" in their address bar when visiting this page.
4. In the codebehind of each search module, input the following code after a user clicks search (search button click handler)

   ```
   Response.Redirect("/Search-Results.aspx?search=" & httpUtility.UrlEncode(TXT_Search.Text))
   ```
5. In your search results module at SearchResults.aspx, in your codebehind page-load function, do this:

   ```
   Dim MyString as String = httpUtility.URLDecode(Request.QueryString("search"))
   ' perform search ...
   ```

Comment: sir
your answer is good but these pages are secure pages and they must be access from that folders only according to requirements.
and there are roles and restritions for those pages so i am not able to put in root folder and i am not able to use my own aspx pages in dotnet nuke.
can you tell me the redirection according to dotnetnuke redirection.
that will more helpfull to me.

Comment: Just go into your DotNetNuke page settings for each of the above and restrict the pages to Admins Only (or a role of your choice). Furthermore, you are free to force-SSL and IP-restrict the pages from your code-behind.

Comment: vey nice sir but my client is strict to not use nay extra aspx pages externally, strictly use of dotnet nuke development ony.

Comment: You cannot run dotnetnuke modules outside of DNN content pages. If you can't do the above method, then you are out of luck. It sounds like you need a standard ASP.NET web application

Comment: kindly provide dotnetnuke module redirecton from one module to other external module. according to my main question. i will Appreciate you.

Comment: It is impossible. You cannot run a DNN module outside of DNN.

Answer (score 3):

Because the controls are in different modules, you'll need to use `Globals.NavigateURL` to navigate to a specific page that the module is on.  If the result.ascx was a control of the same module, you could use `EditUrl` and pass in the control key, but that only working within the same module definition.

In this case, you should probably use `ModuleController.GetModulesByDefinition` to get the Result modules on the portal, then navigate to the page that one of the modules is on.

Comment: i tryed this code also   private ModuleInfo listModuleInfo;
        public ModuleInfo GetModule(string moduleName)
        {
            ModuleController moduleController = new ModuleController();
            listModuleInfo = moduleController.GetModuleByDefinition(this.PortalId, moduleName);
            return listModuleInfo;
        }                                                            to redirect      ActLogUrl = DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(GetModule("testing").TabID, "testing", "mid", GetModule("testing").ModuleID.ToString());     but its not working

Comment: Can you provide some more information about how your project is setup?  Do you have three different desktop modules registered with DNN (each with a module definition with one control)?  Do you have these three controls on three different pages?

When you say that the code doesn't work, are you getting an error (if so, which?) or is it taking you to a URL that doesn't have what you expect?

Comment: i created 3 modules(.ascx control) in 3 different folders and i registered with dnn as different modules so now i want to redirect from search page to result page with parameters but its not allowing.its allowing only if these 3 modules place in one folder and register search control as "view" and result control as "edit". i want place result control in different folder (it must act as common control for EnterpriseSearch and documentsearch controls). so can you please tell me the redirection for different folder modules.

Comment: If they're different modules, then each control will need to be the view control of the module (without a control key), and you'll need to place each module on a page manually (there's no way to access the control outside of an instance of that module).  When redirecting with `Globals.NavigateURL`, pass `string.Empty` as the `controlKey` parameter, and don't pass the `mid` parameter (since you're going to a view control without a control key).

Comment: i will Appreciate you for your grate reply i will try this method.

Comment: @bdukes I am stuck in redirecting from one module(test1) to another module(test2). Globals.NavigateURL has 3 parameter. 1- TabID, 2- ControlKey and 3- Mid parameter. You have suggested to pass blank for control key and nothing form Mid. But what should I pass for TabID? If I don't pass TabID, how can method decide to redirect which module?Can you plz provide example with syntex?

Comment: @NanjiMange, the reality is that you're not redirecting to a module, but to a _page_ which has that module on it.  So that Tab ID (i.e. page ID) is the most important parameter that you're passing to `Globals.NavigateURL`.  You'll want to use the `ModuleController` class to find the module you're interested in, and then redirect using the `TabID` property from that `ModuleInfo` object.

Answer (score 0):

In view control button click event write below code like

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Response.Redirect(Globals.NavigateURL(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID, "WebUserControl", "mid=" + ModuleId.ToString()));          
 }
```

Follow below url instruction and redirection from one page to another page works.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Content/Dnn.Platform/Documentation/Using%20the%20Control%20Panel/Host%20Console/Extensions/Module%20Definitions%20and%20Controls/Adding%20a%20Module%20Control.html